# Highcharts map example not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dictionary, highcharts

I'm trying to reproduce Highcharts maps example but it doesn't works.

When I try to render my chart Google Chrome returns on console:

```
highcharts.js:8 Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17
    X @ highcharts.js:8
    hb.initSeries @ highcharts.js:211
    (anonymous function) @ highcharts.js:233
    o @ highcharts.js:25
    hb.firstRender @ highcharts.js:233
    hb.init @ highcharts.js:211
    (anonymous function) @ data.js:24
    a.(anonymous function) @ highcharts.js:21
    hb.getArgs @ highcharts.js:210
    B.Chart @ highcharts.js:210
    i.Map.i.mapChart @ map.js:57
    E.jQuery.fn.highcharts @ highcharts.js:29
    (anonymous function) @ grafico_map.php:36
    j @ jquery.min.js:2
    k.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
    x @ jquery.min.js:4
    n.prop.on.c @ jquery.min.js:4
    n.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
    r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

My Code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

        <title>Maps Chart</title>       

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


        <script language="JavaScript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=world-population.json&callback=?', function (data) {

                var mapData = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['custom/world']);

                // Correct UK to GB in data
                $.each(data, function () {
                    if (this.code === 'UK') {
                        this.code = 'GB';
                    }
                });

                $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
                    chart : {
                        borderWidth : 1
                    },

                    title: {
                        text: 'World population 2013 by country'
                    },

                    subtitle : {
                        text : 'Demo of Highcharts map with bubbles'
                    },

                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },

                    mapNavigation: {
                        enabled: true,
                        buttonOptions: {
                            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                        }
                    },

                    series : [{
                        name: 'Countries',
                        mapData: mapData,
                        color: '#E0E0E0',
                        enableMouseTracking: false
                    }, {
                        type: 'mapbubble',
                        mapData: mapData,
                        name: 'Population 2013',
                        joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
                        data: data,
                        minSize: 4,
                        maxSize: '12%',
                        tooltip: {
                            pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.z} thousands'
                        }
                    }]
                });

            });
        });

</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any one can help me to find what is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need to load the `highcharts-more.js` before the `map.js` module. This is because the `bubble` chart type is defined in `highcharts-more.js`, and is the basis of the `mapbubble` chart type defined in the `map.js` module.

So just reorder your `<script>` tags, for example like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/Ondkloss/5qzsdpu5/) of it in action.

Comment: Thank you !!! It works very well I'm really sorry about my fault. I don't mind that the order could cause this error !